# Sylius: How to create listener base on Entity Implementing SyliusResourceBundle

Tags: sylius-resource

I am beginner in sylius work and i would like to create adjustement on order item before it will be persist in database. So i create a listener base on sylius.order_item.pre_create event as it is said in the documentation https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.5/book/architecture/events.html

All Sylius bundles are using SyliusResourceBundle, which has some built-in events on this format for exemple

> sylius.resource.pre_create

Her is my Listener Config

```
services:
    app.listener.order_item:
        class: App\EventListener\OrderItemListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: sylius.order_item.pre_create, method: onSyliusOrderItemPreCreate }
```

Her is my Listener Class

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;


use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ShopUserInterface;
use App\Entity\Order\OrderItem;
use App\Entity\Order\Order;
use App\Entity\Order\Adjustement;
use App\Repository\Channel\ChannelPricingRepository;
use Sylius\Component\Channel\Context\ChannelContextInterface;
use Sylius\Component\Order\Factory\AdjustmentFactoryInterface;

class OrderItemListener
{

    public function onSyliusOrderItemPreCreate(GenericEvent $event)
    {
       var_dump(''); die;

        $orderItem = $event->getSubject();
        Assert::isInstanceOf($orderItem, OrderItem::class);     
    }
}
```

But nothing happens when i add a new product to card. What i miss? May be i don't understand well concept or i make thing in wrong way. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution for my problem. In fact when adding product to card route **sylius_shop_ajax_cart_add_item** is called with **post** method. Doing **bin/console debug:router sylius_shop_ajax_cart_add_item**  show that Sylius\Bundle\OrderBundle\Controller\OrderItemController::addAction method is excecuted. In this one **$this->eventDispatcher->dispatchPreEvent(CartActions::ADD, $configuration, $orderItem);** is called and CartActions::ADD = 'add'.
 So the event her is **sylius.order_item.pre_add** not *sylius.order_item.pre_create* as i made it.

```
services:
    app.listener.order_item:
        class: App\EventListener\OrderItemListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: sylius.order_item.pre_add, method: onSyliusOrderItemPreAdd }
```

thanks.